# Kotlin subir PDF con FTPClient al mobil

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy necesitando subir un PDF desde un FTP y guardarlo en Public Storage con KOTLIN

Tengo el mismo código para subir imágenes y funciona a la perfección, pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar para subir PDFs. En realidad me los sube pero con 0kb y no es visible

```
    for (filePdf in ftpFilesPDF)
    {
       if (filePdf.isDirectory)
          continue
       val localFolderPdf = 
File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),SharedApp.prefs.folder + "/photos/${file.name}")
       if(!localFolderPdf.exists())
          localFolderPdf.mkdir()
       val archivoPdf = File(localFolderPdf, filePdf.name)
       val filePdfOutputStream = FileOutputStream(archivoPdf)
       val pw = PrintWriter(filePdfOutputStream)
       pw.println("")
       pw.flush()
       pw.close()
       filePdfOutputStream.close()
       val outputPdf: OutputStream
       outputPdf = FileOutputStream(archivoPdf)
       client.retrieveFile(file.name, outputPdf)
       outputPdf.close()
       filePdfOutputStream.close()
   }
```

Agradecería su ayuda!
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste escribiendo directamente en el filePdfOutputStream ?, parece que el [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) no soporta "raw" bytes.